# Python: How can I include the delimiter in a string split result and add a word in front of delimiter in the result list?

Tags: python, string, split

```
teststring ='two snote words test note test'

print(teststring.partition('note'))
```

Getting the output : `('two snote words test ', 'note', ' test')`

But I want the output like indicated below (here 'bold' is the variable I want to add in front of match) :

```
['two s',bold,'note','words test',bold.'note','test']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split string without delimiter, then add the ith string from the splited list, plus string and the delimiter to a new list.

```
plus_string = 'bold'
delimiter = 'note'
teststring ='two snote words test note test'
splited = teststring.split(delimiter)
result = []

for s in splited:
    result.append(s)

    if splited.index(s) == len(splited) - 1:
        # Do not append plus_string and delimiter
        # to the end of the list.
        break

    result.append(plus_string)
    result.append(delimiter)

print(result)
```

Will print:

```
['two s', 'bold', 'note', ' words test ', 'bold', 'note', ' test']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !!!...actually I was looking for spliting this way for dynamic string(instead of hard coded 'teststring'), forgot to mention this in question.